# Dialog Flow Webhook not working with ngrok

Tags: python, flask, dialogflow-es, ngrok

Issue with Dialogflow ,carried out below steps

1. Enabled Webhook requeston dialogflow and its request
2. Connected with [ngrok](/questions/tagged/ngrok)
3. Calling webhook method from [flask](/questions/tagged/flask)

Below are the images:

Intent Webhook:

[image]

Fullfillment Enabled:

[image]

Ngrok:

[image]

Flask Method:

[image]

```
 @app.route("/webhook",methods=['POST'])
 def main():
      Req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)
      print(Req.get('queryResult'))
      Resp='test'
      return  make_response(jsonify({'fulfillmentText': Resp}))
```

Comment: show your code.  what images?

Comment: this  is it I've added the images too

Comment: How are you testing it and what error are you getting when you test? Are you seeing any activity in ngrok or in the ngrok web interface?

Comment: No activity as such from dialogflow Webdemo Integration ,only if i hit the url in browser I'm getting response on NGROK.NGROK working finr,that itself suggest Dialflow is not sending any request or maybe not detecting the URL

Comment: What does diagnostic info say?  Can you open https://a6499b77.ngrok.io in a web browser and see the request in the terminal?

Comment: is this issue resolved yet? cz i am also facing same issue